# Cannot select Terms on metadata columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata

I created a number of new Managed MetaData columns in SharePoint (O365). I created terms in the term store and made the columns required.

To test everything was working, I added a test document. The three columns added Stated "Required Info" which I thought was a good sign but when I go to add content into these columns, I can't.

I try manually typing something I know is in the term set, it can't find it and won't let me apply/save. I try clicking on the tag icon and no terms load.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

TaxonomyHiddenList is not already updated.
Depending on the amount of site collections in your tenant this can last longer than you exspect.
Just wait until the job has been done. This is a backend process and as far as I know you have no control over it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to term store management tool -> Select the term set-> In the general section, check whether you set owner in the new term set -> In the intended use section, check whether click different use cases.

You can wait for a while, delete managed metadata columns and re-create again.